# Running AppleScript Regex using sed problems

Tags: regex, sed, applescript, data-munging

I'm trying to use sed under AppleScript to execute Regex commands. The goal is to run a series of Regex commands to cleanup text. I've tried to use the TextEdit app as the source for the data to be passed on to the Regex commands. It will not run until I comment out the two expressions that look for isolated ":" and ";".

The script runs and thows no errors, but it also doesn't affect any of the text problems that the regex commnads were to supposed to work on. What can I do to get this to run? I never thought some simple text mungung would be so difficult in AppleScript.

```
tell application "TextEdit" to activate

set the clipboard to ""
tell application "System Events" to keystroke "c" using command down -- copy
delay 1 -- test different values

set selectedText to the clipboard as Unicode text
if selectedText is "" then
    display dialog "Text selection not found"
    return
end if

-- Replace ".  " with ". "
set selectedText to do shell script "echo " & quoted form of selectedText & " | sed 's/\\.  /\\. /g'"

-- Replace "  " with " "
set selectedText to do shell script "echo " & quoted form of selectedText & " | sed 's/  / /g'"

-- Replace "   " with " "
set selectedText to do shell script "echo " & quoted form of selectedText & " | sed 's/   / /g'"

-- Replace ",  " with ", "
set selectedText to do shell script "echo " & quoted form of selectedText & " | sed 's/,  /, /g'"

-- Replace ":" without a space after with ": "
--set selectedText to do shell script "echo " & quoted form of selectedText & " | sed 's/:\([^[:space:]]\)/: \\1/g'"

-- Replace ";" without a space after with "; "
--set selectedText to do shell script "echo " & quoted form of selectedText & " | sed 's/;\([^[:space:]]\)/; \\1/g'"

-- Replace curly quotes with straight quotes
set selectedText to do shell script "echo " & quoted form of selectedText & " | sed 's/[“”‘’]/\"/g'"

-- Replace multiple carriage returns with one carriage return
set selectedText to do shell script "echo " & quoted form of selectedText & " | awk 'BEGIN{RS=\"\";FS=\"\\n\"}{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)if($i)printf(\"%s%s\",$i,i==NF?\"\":\"\\n\")}'"

-- Replace repeated words with one occurrence of the word
set selectedText to do shell script "echo " & quoted form of selectedText & " | sed -E 's/(\\b\\w+\\b)(\\s+\\1)+/\\1/g'"

-- Capitalize the first letter after a period and lowercase the rest
set selectedText to do shell script "echo " & quoted form of selectedText & " | sed -E 's/\\b([a-z])|\\.\\s+(.)/\\U\\1\\L\\2/g'"

set the clipboard to selectedText
delay 1
tell application "System Events" to keystroke "v" using command down -- paste
```

I have commented out the the two regex commands that keep the script from running and the script will runout returns nothing.

Answer (score 0):

You missed backslashes to escape your backslashes.

```
" | sed 's/;\([^[:space:]]\)/; \\1/g'"
------------^-------------^-----------
            here          and here
```

Use this instead:

```
" | sed 's/;\\([^[:space:]]\\)/; \\1/g'"
```

Explanation:
I'm not sure how applescript behave in such cases, but I'll guess that your command turned into something like this:

```
echo something | sed 's/;([^[:space:]])/; \1/g'
```

and since you use BRE (inconsistently by the way), sed looks for literal parenthesis around you non-space character.

Comment: Thanks for that insight. I'll dig back into it tonight with new insight.